# How can I group RegEx correctly with '|'?

Tags: python, python-re

I want to match different RegEx to a string. For example

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import os
import re

s = "rechnungsnr. 234342341"

re_nu = re.compile(r".?rechnung[s]*\s*nr[.]*[:]*\s*(\w*\d+[-.]?\d*)")

rn = re_nu.search(s)
rechnungsnr = (rn.groups())
print(rechnungsnr)
print(rn)
print(rn.group(1))
```

This yields me the correct group (the number after the text):

```
('234342341',)
<re.Match object; span=(0, 22), match='rechnungsnr. 234342341'>
234342341
```

However, if I expand the RegEx with '|' I get different results:

```
s = "rechnungsnr. 234342341"

re_nu = re.compile(r"rechnungs\s?nummer[:]*\s*(\w*\d+[-.]?\d*)|rechnung(?::*)(?:\s*)((?:\w*)(?:\d+)[-.]?(?:\d*))|.?rechnung[s]*\s*nr[.]*[:]*\s*(\w*\d+[-.]?\d*)|   \
                    belegnummer(?::*)(?:\s*)((?:\w*)(?:\d+)[-.]?(?:\d*))|beleg(?:s*)[-.]?nr(?:.*)(?::*)(?:\s*)((?:\w*)(?:\d+)[-.]?(?:\d*))")

rn = re_nu.search(s)
rechnungsnr = (rn.groups())
print(rechnungsnr)
print(rn)
print(rn.group(1))
```

As in I get 2 "none" groups before the number I want to extract:

```
(None, None, '234342341', None, None)
<re.Match object; span=(0, 22), match='rechnungsnr. 234342341'>
None
```

How can I change the code such that the number is always the first group? The goal of the RegEx is to get the number after the string. The string can be any name for a invoice number (in German). For example the number could come after "rechnungsnummer" but also after "rechnungs nr." but also after "rechnungs nr:" and so on...

Comment: can you describe what the regex's goal?

Comment: There might be an easier way - can you give a sample list of strings that you are trying to match?

Comment: I added the goal of the regex. The strings will be text taken from invoices.

Comment: Make sure there is only one group that matches the number. "refactor" the regular expression so that it has the form `(?:...)(...)`, where the first non-capture group matches anything that could precede the number and the capture group matches the number itself. The branches go *inside* the non-capture group.

Comment: It could be any regular expression, thats why I cannot make any of the non-capturing. The problems seems to be that the code runs over the regular expressions seperated by "|" and if he does not find them he groups a "none".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `rn.groups()` is returning a tuple, you can do list comprehension like this:

```
[item for item in rn.groups() if item is not None]
```

> For example the number could come after "rechnungsnummer" but also after "rechnungs nr." but also after "rechnungs nr:" and so on...

If this is true in all cases, then the list comprehension will only ever return a list with a single element.

Comment: I think this is the right approach to use as a quick and dirty solution. Thank you!